# Transparent Firewall using macOS pf

Tags: network, macos, ethernet

I'm trying to setup a transparent firewall with a Mac mini running macOS Sierra.
Basically I'm trying to do this (just with macOS): [A Transparent Firewall Using OpenBSD](https://binblog.info/2012/06/26/a-transparent-firewall-using-openbsd/)

This is my network setup:

```
Internet <-ethernet-> Router <-ethernet->en0 Mac mini en4<-ethernet-> AppleTV
```

The Router also connects to several other devices via Wifi.

Now here's what I did on the Mac mini to make it a transparent firewall:

1. I setup the bridge via these commands:

   ```
   sudo ifconfig bridge1 create
   sudo ifconfig bridge1 addm en0 addm en4
   sudo ifconfig bridge1 up
   ```

From the AppleTV's perspective it's now like the Mac mini doesn't exist.

2. I setup pf by adding this to `/etc/pf.conf`:

   ```
   anchor "org.user"
   load anchor "org.user" from "/etc/pf.anchors/org.user"
   ```

   and created `/etc/pf.anchors/org.user` with this content:

   ```
   # skip lo0
   set skip on lo0

   # options
   set block-policy drop

   # rules
   block on en4 all
   ```

   Then I "restarted" pf with the new rules:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
   sudo pfctl -e
   ```

Now I would expect no traffic from AppleTV to go out into the network. But AppleTV still works like I never setup those pf rules.

What am I missing?

PS: Here's the ifconfig output:

```
MacMini:~ Daniel$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether a8:20:66:1e:9a:62 
    inet6 fe80::1cca:5c4b:64a7:7350%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4 
    inet6 2a02:8070:a89:8f00:181c:12bc:a98c:7229 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    inet6 2a02:8070:a89:8f00:d489:89da:9083:17d8 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    inet6 2a02:8070:a89:8f00::9 prefixlen 64 dynamic 
    inet 192.168.0.137 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet>)
    status: active
en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING>
    ether 00:23:56:1c:82:26 
    inet6 fe80::223:56ff:fe1c:8226%en4 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
en1: flags=8823<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 20:c9:d0:93:5e:f1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr 00:3e:e1:ff:fe:b3:04:08 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en3: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 32:00:1b:30:40:80 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 32:00:1b:30:40:80 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 8 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:c9:d0:93:5e:f1 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8902<BROADCAST,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 8e:36:65:e0:9a:1e 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::9a58:4bd5:9f77:f77a%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::1e34:cc36:613b:1ee6%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
    inet 10.0.1.16 --> 1.0.0.1 netmask 0xffffff00 
bridge1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether aa:20:66:e1:cb:01 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 4 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    media: autoselect
    status: active
MacMini:~ Daniel$
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - `ifconfig` output was added.

Comment: Which IPs/mask/gw did you assign to en0 and en4 **before** creating the bridge?

Comment: Both were set to DHCP. En0 got an IP (192.168.0.137/255.255.255.0/192.168.0.1)) from the router. En4 got a self assigned IP (169.254.75.147/255.255.0.0/none).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really doubt that you will get this to work with system tools. And though I'm not familiar with OpenBSD I also doubt that the linked example works without further mods with one exception: filtering by MAC addresses after enabling bridge packet tagging.

In OS X bridge packet tagging (i.e. `ifconfig bridge1 rule pass in on en4 src 00:17:f2:f8:1a:3d tag APPLETV`) isn't possible though.

*pf* in OS X is a layer-3 packet filter. It relies on IP-addresses and doesn't really work with interface names or MAC-addresses. So using an interface name in a rule (e.g. `block on en4 all`) is internally translated to `block on <IP of en4> all` and in your case `block nothing` because en4 has no IP-address.

Even after assigning an IP to en4 you wouldn't be able to block AppleTV traffic to the outside world because these IP-packets neither contain `<IP of en4>` as source nor as destination address.

Comment: Makes sense to me so it looks like it's back to the drawing board. Do you have an idea how I can achieve what I want to do? http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/265486/215988

Comment: I basically want all traffic coming from the en4-network targeted to an internet location to be sent through a VPN. At the same time I want all local traffic between en0-NW and en4-NW to stay the same (as if en0 and en4 were bridged).